# Is the passed string anywhere in another string? Java

Tags: java, string, search

So I am having a problem on what seems to be a really simple thing that I just can't wrap my mind around at the moment.

I am trying to determine if a String that is passed to a certain method is a valid Time Zone abbreviation (PDT, EST, etc.) I have a string that just lists out all 100 or so abbreviations I am supposed to use with just a space in between each one and I want to be able to check if the abbreviation passed is anywhere in the long string I have listed and then pass back en error message if it isn't.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to search the long string? Or should I not be using a string in the first place? Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me!

Comment: There are simple String methods in the API (ex. `contains()`).  Did you try to google?  For example, "java validate timestamp":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902310/how-do-i-validate-a-timestamp

Comment: -1 for not looking at the Java documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using a string in the first place.

Add all your possibilities to a static [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and then call `contains()` with your input string.

Even better, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) can probably validate timezones for you, or remove the problem that you're trying to solve by checking timezone strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `contains` on the long String. Alternatively you could use an array instead of the long String, which may be easier to maintain if more abbreviations are added.

For an array of abbreviations, use `ArrayUtils.contains` (which is part of the Apache Commons, not the standard library).

Comment: You can use `contains` in a string, but the list in the string must have separator characters before/between/after, and you must pre/post-pend the same characters to the search argument before searching.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a String for that.

If your Timezones string is something like:

```
String TIMEZONES = "PDT EST CET ..."
```

Then you can convert to a `Set<String>` with next code:

```
Set<String> VALID_TZS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(TIMEZONES.split(" ")));
```

And to check if your code is a valid timezone:

```
boolean isValidTZ(String tz) {
    return VALID_TZS.contains(tz);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String ALL_ABRBREVIATIONS = ...; // all possible

public boolean isValid(String toCheck) {
  return ALL_ABRBREVIATIONS.contains(toCheck);
}
```