# How to check if string representing timestamp is valid date in Java?

Tags: java, date

Previously I check [How do I validate a timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902310/how-do-i-validate-a-timestamp) and I try to base my code on that, I have an string that has the date: `String date = "2013-01-28 20:46:34"` and I want to check if is valid by calling `isTimeStampValid` method, their implementation is:

```
    public boolean isTimeStampValid(String timeStamp)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss");

        try{
            format.parse(timeStamp);
            return true;
        }
        catch(ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But the method returns `false` and I suspect that "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss" is incorrect but I didn't found any solution ([SimpleDateFormat java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). How can I do the method return `true` when appropiate?

Comment: `HH-mm:ss` vs `20:46:34`.

Comment: Typo in your format: Change the `-` in `HH-mm` to `HH:mm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss");
```

and

```
String date = "2013-01-28 20:46:34"
```

They do not match. It should be

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Note `:` instead of `-` between `HH` and `mm`

Answer (score 2):

change your dateFormat from `"yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` ("-" vs. ":")